# Use a single ng-model to filter results and display filter method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have an HTML select element that gives some options on how to sort a list, it looks like this:

```
<select ng-init="sortMethod=sortMethods[0]" ng-model="sortMethod">
  <option ng-repeat="sortMethod in sortMethods">{{sortMethod}}</option>
</select>
```

and here's sortMethod:

```
$scope.sortMethods = ['created', 'likes.count'];
```

I'm using sortMethod to sort a bunch of objects:

```
<li ng-repeat="story in feedData|orderBy:sortMethod">
  Panel Count: {{story.frameURIs.length}}
</li>
```

And all of this works just fine, but the issue is that the options in the select box are ugly, it displays "created" and 'likes.count", but it should say something like "Most Recent" and "Most Popular".

I tried to changing sortMethod to an array of objects like this:

```
$scope.sortMethods = [{'displayVal': 'Most Recent', 'sortVal': 'created'}, {'displayVal': 'Most Popular', 'sortVal': 'likes.count'}];
```

and displaying `sortMethod.displayVal` in the `select` element, and using `<li ng-repeat="story in feedData|orderBy:sortMethod.sortVal"` but that seems to sort them in a seemingly random order. How do I make pretty select options without changing the info in feedData? feedData comes from another party and I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking in the right direction - i.e. of creating the proper View Model for `sortMethods`.

You should take a look at how to use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#usage) to generate options for your select. It allows you to set display values and what the selected object is.

Specifically, for your case you could select the entire `sortMethod` object (this would be assigned to the `ngModel`), but display the label of `sortMethod.displayVal`. Then, you could use the `sortVal` in the filtering itself.

So, it could look like so:

```
<select ng-model="selectedSortMethod"
      ng-options="sortMethod as sortMethod.displayVal for sortMethod in sortMethods">
</select>

<li ng-repeat="story in feedData|orderBy:selectedSortMethod.sortVal">
  Panel Count: {{story.frameURIs.length}}
</li>
```

Then in the controller:

```
// as you did in your example
$scope.sortMethods = [
   {displayVal: 'Most Recent',  sortVal: 'created'}, 
   {displayVal: 'Most Popular', sortVal: 'likes.count'}
];

$scope.selectedSortMethod = $scope.sortMethods[0];
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ujJajJhQaOPll4esXiEm?p=preview)